# A view with internal variables

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I want to fetch the top x for each value of another column. For doing this I have the following query

```
SELECT *, 
       (@num := IF(@job = job_id, @num + 1, IF(@job := job_id, 1, 1))) row_number
FROM job_user_rank t
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @num := 0, @job := null) c
where is_match = 1
ORDER BY job_id, is_match DESC, rank DESC
```

I then wrap this query and add a `where row_number <= ?`, however I want to make that inner query into a view instead, but I get the following error `[HY000][1351] View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`, how can I get around that?

Comment: Why do you want a view? Views are essentially pointless in MySQL (as far as I can tell )

Comment: @Strawberry because I have a complex query I want to hide away and maybe (not decided yet) limit whom has access to the underlying table.

Comment: Not sure, but this limitation might be lifted with MySQL 8.0 when you use ROW_NUMBER() OVER() instead of variables. Other than that, your only option would be to use a stored procedure instead.

Comment: A complex query is no argument at all. If anything, and particularly in regards to performance, the more complex the query, the less useful a view would be. I would handle privileges in application code.